# Convert Floated Divs/Images into single Image

Tags: asp.net, css, html

Bit of a weird one here - I've created a map with various image overlays floated over the top using CSS for a web app which is built in asp.net; it looks and works fine in the browser, however the page the map appears in is sometimes converted to a Word document for editing, after conversion the map either disappears if using background divs, or displays all it's component parts consecutively if using img tags.

Is there any way I can convert the map into a single image for display and conversion?

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to do a once-off conversion, or be able to automate it so that people can elect to convert the entire map into an image at whim?

Comment: I think the converted image should be the one displayed on the webpage; users convert the page by saving it as a htm file and using a 3rd party plugin to convert it to Word format; so I suppose that counts as one-off every time the page loads.

Answer (score 0):

Ok - I've decided the easiest way to do this is to use the .NET Graphics classes to composite all my images and text into a single image and display that at runtime.